# Make it possible to retract reopen votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, retracted-flags

It is possible to retract close votes by clicking on the close button again and then clicking on "Retract close vote", but it doesn't seem to be possible to retract reopen votes (clicking the reopen button again just gives me an error message that I already voted to reopen).

Not having the ability to retract re-open votes is inconsistent, since most (if not all) other vote types can be undone (albeit with some limitations).

And regretfully, sometimes further edits by the question author work to make the question less suitable to be re-opened than previous revisions.

A way to implement this would be doing so that clicking the reopen button again would ask if the user really wants to retract their reopen vote. A message like this would be good, with emphasis on the word "retract" so that the user can easily see that clicking OK will retract the reopen vote:

> You've already voted to reopen this question. Do you really want to RETRACT your reopen vote?
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd><kbd>Cancel</kbd>

This is just a suggestion, any other message would be fine too.

Can we get the ability to retract reopen votes?

Comment: I'm not exactly opposed to this since it exists in the opposite way, but I personally feel like...if you click to reopen you've already convinced yourself that this *should* be reopened.  What use cases do you see that causes you to correctly rethink on reopening a question?  They likely exist but I wanna know what you're thinking.

Comment: @Makoto For example if a comment is posted after I voted to reopen that gives a good reason for it to stay closed. It happened once that I got a question in the reopen queue and user who voted to reopen gave a seemingly good reason to reopen it, so I voted to reopen it, but then after that another user responded to the comment and gave an even better reason for it to stay closed so I wanted to retract my reopen vote but I couldn't.

Comment: @Makoto What about reaching for edit and accidentally hitting reopen? ;)  It would also be nice to have this delete and undelete votes.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  There's already an alert modal that pops up when you attempt to reopen a question.  If you on autopilot click through that, then you were already warned IMO...

Comment: @DonaldDuck:  My personal opinion on this is, if you can be swayed by what others say about the question's quality, you're not in a position to objectively say that it should be reopened *or* closed, and should look to recuse yourself immediately from that decision.

Comment: @Makoto Wouldn't retracting the vote be the way to recuse oneself?

Comment: What kind of Mickey Mouse suggestion is this? Oh, wait...

Comment: @BJMyers:  By that point the vote(s) would have been cast.  My point is simple:  to be able to say whether or not a question should be reopened should be one you are prepared to defend.  It's not something to just be taken at a whim.  Again, I'm not necessarily opposed to the idea but I really want to hear a convincing use case for it before I offer more support than what I am now.

Comment: @Makoto Not necessarily. If I totally agree with the comment posted after having cast my reopen vote but haven't thought of that, it might make me change my mind. Especially for duplicates, there are a lot of borderline cases.

Comment: @Makoto There was a case where a question asking why Qt wouldn't display their image that was closed as a duplicate of a question asking which image dimensions Qt supports. I voted to reopen it because the OP's image's dimensions were smaller than the maximum dimensions supported, but then it turned out that there was a detail in one of the answers to the other question (not the accepted one) giving another condition for the image format to be supported, which applied to the OP's image.

Comment: I've had the case a few times, and it was most often an error of my part (for example a wrong choice of question when closing as duplicate). My usual workaround is to go to a chat room and have other users fix it. [exhibit 1](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=38365670#38365670).

Comment: [Also requested on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes).

Comment: @DonaldDuck: If the answer to question B is buried in a tangential note in an unaccepted answer to question A, then they're probably not duplicates. IMO, a reasonable rule of thumb is that question B is a duplicate of question A if *any good answer* to A would necessarily also answer B. In practice, moreover, one can often reasonably approximate "any good answer" with "the accepted answer", although occasionally that assumption breaks down. (That said, I do support this feature req; it just makes sense that if we can retract close votes, we should be able to retract reopen votes too.)

Comment: @Makoto, One use case is when the question is edited by the OP to become off-topic, and the OP refuses to change it back or reverts your edit changing it back. I'd consider that rare, but as with most things there is *always* the chance of user error. Being able to undo all actions, or at least as much as possible, is generally good UX.

Comment: @Makyen:  For the most part I think I'll support this philosophy; other comments have thus convinced me.  However, your use case is appropriate for mod flags and not reversals, since you're not going to be getting anywhere with someone who keeps rolling edits back.

Comment: @Makoto: Right, you're not going to get anywhere with the user, so you want to retract your reopen-vote on a now off-topic question from an OP who's not wiling to comply with site policy. Yes, multiple edit reverts is worth a mod-flag, but I'd explain OT to OP & ask them why instead of just reverting again. In the situation described, I'd probably just disengage and let it Roomba (after reopen votes age away), or delete vote (when possible). Sure, if the OP was belligerent, I'd mod-flag, but I'd tend to just let it die. In the situation described, me mod-flagging would depend on the details.

Comment: I'd love to see a feature like this. But I'd have to admit, it doesn't really sound like a feature worth investing in, unless it's _really_ cheap to implement (say, an hour's time). I just don't believe the need for something like this comes up that much. Retracting of close votes would be a lot more common, because the OP is (in theory) motivated to improve their post and fix whatever problem led to a close vote. But retracting reopen votes wouldn't happen due to changes in the facts, but rather changes in the voter's interpretation. Not nearly as critical or as common.

Comment: +1 and I have a real use case for this. I answered a question which was not, as originally asked, about a NullReferenceException. After we in comments suggested a syntax fix an NRE then became an issue and OP added that error to the question. It was then closed  as a dupe of the canonical NRE answer. I rolled the question back and cast a reopen vote. Today I discovered a genuine duplicate target and a gold badge wearer changed the duplicate target for me. It would be right and proper for me to now retract my reopen vote but I cannot.

Comment: “It is possible to retract close votes by clicking on the close button again and then clicking on "Retract close vote"” I can’t find even this feature. I often want to retract close votes but don’t see how to do it.

Comment: @matt [See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CScjU.png)

Comment: Should be merged to StackExcange https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes

Comment: Another case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325193/python-matplotlib-2-2-2-sort-y-axis-values?noredirect=1#comment89629058_51325193 Appeared first to be a duplicate (closed), then OP confirmed that their version is not compatible with the duplicate problem (reopen vote), then the OP found out that they falsely assumed that all variables were integers (something they had been asked before). I should be able to retract my vote given that the situation has changed.

Comment: I think that this would be a good feature. I just clicked reopen after a new contributor edited a question in response to a comment, improving the quality of the question. I like to encourage such contributors for being responsive to constructive criticism, and at first glance I thought that their edit made it a nonduplicate. But then I thought about it a bit more and realized that it was just a better-written but still duplicate question. It doesn't happen much, but there have been a couple of times I have wanted to retract a reopen vote. Making it possible, could help with the reopen queue.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This has been implemented.

This reuses the same backend code and logic as for retracting close votes, so the behavior should be exactly the same.

Comment: I guess that means if you retract a re-open vote you're unable to vote again?

Comment: @Nick Yeah, it does.  I _think_ it wouldn't be a huge code change to allow it on both, maybe with the same criteria for voting as aged-out votes, but that's a bigger product decision.

Comment: Meh, I think it would be more helpful for close votes (in particular, VtC as unclear/too broad, then when more info was added, switching to duplicate specifically), but that can be considered later, just wanted to be sure of how this worked before I go retracting re-open votes :p. Ta

Comment: @BrianNickel is there a way to re-use the code that lets you mod-flag or red flag a post on which you retracted a flag, to be able to duplicate close vote?

Comment: @Luuklag Sounds like a new [meta-tag:feature-request]... :-)

Comment: @TylerH go ahead if you want to ;)

Comment: You might want to update [this feature request on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes) as well.

Comment: Is this only for Stack Overflow? If no, really better post something on MSE as it's major change that deserve to be announced to everyone, not only those who happen to visit MSO.

Comment: Can you add the ability to vote to reopen again? I can't count how many times I've miss clicked the button by going too fast and not seeing that I was retracting my vote permanently.

Answer (score 32):

### I support this feature request

I wanted to retract a reopen vote a couple of times before. Users in the comments have been asking for valid use cases, here's one that happened to me very recently:

1. A gold badge holder dup-hammered a question with a dup target that was about a different problem.
2. I left a comment explaining this to the gold badge holder.
3. I tried to find an actual duplicate myself but I couldn't find one.
4. I voted to reopen the question.
5. A few hours later, that user saw my comment, admitted that it was not the correct dup target but they managed to find one, so they edited the duplicates list replacing the wrong dup target with a valid one.
6. Now, I agree that the question is rightfully closed. Yet, I can't retract my reopen vote.

There are other valid use cases as well, like [the one Makyen mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355481/make-it-possible-to-retract-reopen-votes/403402#comment507059_355481) in the comments. In addition to that, having the ability to retract close votes but not reopen votes just doesn't feel right.