# How to revoke a reopen vote

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I voted to reopen a question closed as a duplicate because (what I thought) was the marked duplicate didn't answer the question at all.

I was mistaken...

What I interpreted as the marked duplicate was really just a link the closer posted in the comments. The actual duplicate, which appeared at the top of the question, did answer my question.

So, now there is no need for my vote to reopen. I would like to revoke the vote/request as I have realized the error. How do I do this?

Comment: I thought you needed 3k rep to be able to cast re-open votes?

Comment: @yivi on your own posts I believe you can cast a re-open at 150. Anyway mhatch - I've found the re-open review task created by your vote and voted leave closed on it - so that'll have expired your vote.

Comment: @JonClements That doesn't expire the reopen vote, it just *starts* the timer on the reopen vote.  Until the review is closed the clock doesn't even start.

Comment: @Servy I could have phrased that much better... The review is now completed - so that'll move things forward slightly quicker...

Comment: Related: [Make it possible to retract reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355481/4284627)

Comment: @JonClements Would it help if a lot of people cast Leave Closed votes on it? Why not link the review if so?

Comment: @jpmc26 moderator votes in review queues are binding so there's no review task to link to as it got completed on my "leave closed" vote.

Answer (score 18):

You can't.  There is no way to revoke a reopen vote.  The best you can do is re-close the question if/when the question is reopened.

Note that reopen votes do expire eventually, so if it isn't reopened after a while the vote will go away.

Comment: Does anyone know the time period until it expires?

Comment: @mhatch [either 4 or 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/165773) depending on whether question has more or less than 100 views

Answer (score 5):

As already noted by others, there's currently no way to retract a reopen vote.

If you've mistakenly voted to reopen a question, and would like to minimize any resulting confusion or waste of time, the best thing you can do is leave a comment under the question explaining your mistake.  Reviewers in the reopen review queue will see your comment, and will most likely vote to leave the question closed.

(Note that [reopen review can be pretty harsh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306378/how-to-distinguish-audits-from-real-reviews-in-sede-data/306399#306399), with less than 10% of all review tasks resulting in the question actually being reopened.  Unless your question looks like it *obviously* should never have been closed, the odds are that the reviewers will vote to leave it closed anyway.  But at least leaving a comment may save a few seconds of their time.)

Once your vote has been declined by reviewers, it will expire and disappear completely after a few days.  But even before it does, the only way anyone will even notice its existence is if they somehow stumble across your closed question and happen to glance at the little "reopen (1)" link below it.