# Doesn't the Stack Overflow community like innovative things?

Tags: discussion

I have seen that when Stack Overflow introduces a new thing, the introduction post or beta release receives so many downvotes.

The latest example is [Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow). which has a score of -265 at the moment.

I am curious to know the reason for that. Doesn't the Stack Overflow community like innovative things or is there any other reason?

Comment: *"I am curious to know the reason for that"* - Did you read the answers? I'm pretty sure they cover it

Comment: Votes on Meta mean agreement. Not many people agree with Collectives, if you read the comments.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is what I consider bad science. A good scientist has a thesis and then goes out of their way to prove it is *wrong*; a bad scientist does the exact opposite and will commit to malpractice such as tunnel vision, manipulating data and cherry picking. You just pick one case and pretend that it is a trend to save yourself a whole lot of time and effort, you took no time to prove you're wrong. If you had, you would have been able to provide at least two items on Robert Longson's list to counter your own claim.

Comment: Maybe people like innovative things that are good, and dislike those that are bad.

Answer (score 23):

You've pulled out one example and you're saying that proves everything is unpopular. Here's some rather popular new features as counterexamples...

| Feature | Date | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Unpinning accepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow) | September 2021 | > 350 |
| [Retract reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355481/make-it-possible-to-retract-reopen-votes) | August 2021 | > 130 |
| [Table support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) | December 2020 | > 700 |
| [Dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits) | June 2020 | > 400 |
| [Follow posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) | March 2020 | > 200 |
| [Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams) | 2018 | > 300 |

The complete list of new features is [maintained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). I've just picked out some of the changes that people notice as they are commonly used. Some others, such as [allowing moderators to flag comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360819/165773) wouldn't make too much difference to most of us.

Comment: What you mentioned in your answer & what I thought was really different, Since I am not a native English speaker it is hard to tell it. I am sorry about that. I mean main adding features like adding collective, adding documentation(however, I know it failed,), adding android app, etc I mean a big new parts not like your answer

Comment: Surely teams is as big a feature as the others you mentioned?

Comment: @PresidentofFoolishPeople As Robert said, both Teams and Collectives are big features and they're both commercial products. The community liked one and not the other, so it has nothing to do with "innovation", big features, or products that make money. It has to do with other reasons like the value of the product/feature. As to the Android app (and the iOS one), that's not something the community didn't like. The _company_ just decided that they don't have enough resources to maintain mobile apps. I think that most users actually want to have those apps back.

Comment: You could add *[version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers)* to your list.

Comment: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) is also at a positive score of 217. Not the kind of change OP was talking about but still a big change that has had overall positive reception.

Comment: I've never liked apps. What's wrong with a well written, browser-compliant HTML page? Apps only seem to fragment what was intended to be to be a universal common resource.

Answer (score 14):

> Doesn't the Stack Overflow community like innovative things?

We like innovative things - what we do not like are features shoved down our throats from out of nowhere (because early participants [had to sign NDAs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408600/11407695)) with a clear goal of capitalizing on community effort while:

- [not taking into account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367572/11407695) failures of the past features with similar goals (minus capitalization) and, subsequently, flaws (also known as the Documentation project)
- not giving the community (including moderators and even community managers) the tools to curate the content generated as a result of the "thing"
- releasing a public Beta version in a state that is, essentially, Alpha (given that Collectives had *around a year* of development, this is hardly acceptable)